# Is it possible to exploit an image field in which I can upload any file?

Tags: penetration-test, asp.net, file-upload

I'm pentesting this web application developed in ASP.NET.

I've found that I can upload any file as profile photo. When I later visit the profile page the site tries to display it like this:

```
<img src="../attachments/open.aspx?Key=10350&ute=20069" />
```

So I have the possibility to upload any kind of file and they will be requested as images, but I don't have any control on the image path.

Also I know that the image is uploaded as binary in the database, so is not phisically in the webserver.

Is there a way to exploit this? I haven't found anything yet.

EDIT: since my question has been put on hold and I don't know how to narrow down my question, can someone suggest me what kind of vulnerability should I look for? What course of action would an expert take?

Comment: Whoops, reading comprehension fail with the answer I had. I missed the fact that "open.aspx" is probably a script meant to open image files, and somehow thought that it was a filename you'd supplied. Bedtime for me, I think.

Comment: You might try with SVG. See https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-DeGraaf-SVG-Exploiting-Browsers-Without-Image-Parsing-Bugs.pdf

Comment: You might give this a watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPqVVhxhqmY "The Little JPEG That Could (Hack Your Organization)" Even it's not susceptible you'll learn something really cool. :)

Comment: Are you sure it is uploaded to a file system? Could it be that the images are uploaded in a database? What happens if you try nullbyte injection? Meaning, upload a shell.aspx%00.png or something similar.

Comment: I'm quite sure they are uploaded in a database. I'm looking into nullbyte injection and I'm pursuing the SVG way too. I'll post the results.